# Converting File to MultipartFile using CommonsMultipartFile

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to make a POST request with a MultipartFile.
First I want to convert a File into a MultipartFile:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/plain", false, file.getName(), (int) file.length(), file.getParentFile());
fileItem.getOutputStream();
MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

I'm getting this message under CommonsMultipartFile:

> The type org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I cannot figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that you are missing a required library.

You should add [`commons-fileupload`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1) in your classpath. If you are using Maven, add this dependency to your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If not, just download the JAR and add it manually to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks!
Now i'm getting the the constructor for CommonsMultipartFile(DiskFileItem item) is undified...

Comment: @ItaiSoudry Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: Version 3.6.4.REALEASE

Comment: @ItaiSoudry 3.6.4 doesn't exist but the constructor only took a FileItem in Spring 2. For Spring 3 and 4, there is no such constructor. I suggest you post another question for this.